# Fatal error: Index out of range when updating data source of table

Tags: swift, tableview, nstableview

can anyone provide clarification on why my code is throwing index out of range when i try to add an item to this array? Other answers around the web are situational based and don't provide a great understanding of how to rectify the error.

Here is the code for adding to the array -

```
@IBAction func refreshData(_ sender: Any) {
        let type = "type"
        let cost = dataAdded.shared.cost
        let details = dataAdded.shared.details
        let count = data?.count

        (data!)[count! + 1] = [
        "type" : type,
        "details" : details,
        "cost" : cost
            ] as! [String : String]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

And here is the code for producing the TableView -

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return (data?.count)!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let item = (data!)[row]
        let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: (tableColumn!.identifier), owner: self) as? NSTableCellView
        cell?.textField?.stringValue = item[(tableColumn?.identifier.rawValue)!]!
        return cell
    }
```

The array is declared like this -

```
var data: [[String: String]]?
```

Could this be an issue?

Comment: Image you have no items. So `let count = data?.count` is 0. But you want to add already `data[1]`. No. Use `append()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to init the array as your current declaration is nil

```
var data =  [[String: String]]()
```

and append to the array , also it's better to have a

```
struct Item {

    let type:String
    let details:String
    let cost:String

}
```

---

```
var data =  [Item]()
data.append(Item(type: type, details: details, cost: cost))
```

Comment: thank you, when I use the method data.append xcode returns the error 'Value of type '[[String : String]]?' has no member 'append' ' I cannot find any documentation on this error?

Comment: thank you, when I use the method data.append xcode returns the error 'Value of type '[[String : String]]?' has no member 'append' ' I cannot find any documentation on this error?

Comment: change declaration as in answer , you can do `data?.append` instead of `data.append` but it ill crash also as the array isn't initated

Answer (score 1):

In moment when you're trying to set element on position `count + 1` your array isn't initialized, because you just define type of your array. To fix this, first create empty array

```
var data = [[String: String]]()
```

then you can instead of assigning element on unexisting index append new element to your array

```
data.append(["type" : type,
             "details" : details,
             "cost" : cost])
```

Comment: thank you, when I use the method data.append xcode returns the error 'Value of type '[[String : String]]?' has no member 'append' ' I cannot find any documentation on this error?

Comment: @JermainD didnt you forget to create empty array?